# Windows Server 2016 adding Storage Pool, "Incorrect Function" from physical disk

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

I have a server running Server 2016 Core acting as a hypervisor.  I am now setting up an Azure Backup Server as a VM on that machine.  As per the instructions, the backup server needs a storage pool to use as a staging area.

The server previously had several drives arranged as a RAID 6 array used for the various other things, and I added a single additional drive to use as a stating area.  Using Server Manager (running remotely), I am trying to create the storage pool.  The physical drive appears correctly:

[image: Server Manager -> Storage Pool]

I then right click on the drive, and select "New Storage Pool".  When I go through the wizard, and try to create the pool, I get an error that the process couldn't be completed because the physical drive returned a "Incorrect Function" error:
[image: Storage Pool Wizard Error]

If it matters, HV1 is the hypervisor, the screenshots of Server Manager are from an instance of Win Server 2016 that is running as a VM on that hypervisor and acting as the primary (and only) domain controller, and the Azure Backup Server will also be a VM running on the same hypervisor.  All three are part of the same domain.

When logged into HV1 (command line only since it's a Core), the drive is visible as drive "E:", and diskpart shows it as an online disk with a small reserved partition (not sure where that came from) and the rest as a single primary partition which corresponds to the E: volume.

Googling for this has not revealed any info, and, unfortunately, I'm far from an expert on this, but there's no one else who can do it.  Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

ETA:
As requested, I ran Get-PhysicalDisk on they Hypervisor.  Here's what I got:

```
PS E:\> Get-PhysicalDisk

FriendlyName       SerialNumber                     CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------------       ------------                     ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
AVAGO MR9361-8i    000b899f1d7bc16b23efd78b09b00506 True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select    931 GB
SATADOM-SL 3ME3 V2 BCA11708100130109                False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 119.24 GB
AVAGO MR9361-8i    00c579c90543a3b221efd78b09b00506 False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   1.86 TB
```

The first disk listed, the 931GB one, is the one I'm trying to add.

Comment: Run in PowerShell "Get-PhysicalDisk" and show the output. AFAIK the Disk must be erased and has GPT partition to Pool them.

Comment: @Stuka - added output in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I seem to have figured it out, though it still seems odd to me.

The problem was creating a volume.  Apparently it needs a partition, but not a volume, in order to create the storage pool.  I was unable to find this info, but arrived at the result experimentally, based on Stuka's comment that the disk must be erase.

Comment: That's great we are here to help :)